# Models of ZF with more elements than ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Clearly a model of ZFC has as many ordinals as elements. Does this hold for models of ZF? In particular, if this holds for uncountable transitive models of ZF, then they are subject to Shoenfield absoluteness.

Comment: No, this does not hold for $\mathsf{ZF}$. See for instance [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/129768/6085) and the references mentioned there.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a subtlety to your first sentence. It is true that if $M$ is a model of ZFC, then $M$ has the same cardinality as $Ord^M$, viewed externally. However, *internally* this might break down: there could be no *definable-in-$M$* surjection from $Ord^M$ to $M$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move this off the unanswered queue:

The $\mathsf{ZFC}$ situation is a bit subtle. For any $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ we have $\vert Ord^M\vert=\vert M\vert$. However, this may not be internal: there may be no $M$-definable class bijection $Ord^M\cong M$ (even using a parameter from $M$). Indeed, such a definable bijection exists iff we have $M$ satisfies global choice or equivalently $M\models \exists x(V=HOD(x))$.

For $\mathsf{ZF}$ even the external equipollence fails. In fact we have the following extraordinary situation:

> **(Friedman)**: Suppose $M$ is a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$. Then there is a transitive $N\models\mathsf{ZF}$ with $Ord^M=Ord^N$ and $M\subseteq N$ such that $\vert N\vert=$ [$\beth_{Ord^M}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

This leaves open the question of how extremely we can have $\vert M\vert>\vert Ord^M\vert$ for *uncountable-height* transitive (or even nontransitive) $M\models\mathsf{ZF}$. I have to assume the situation isn't any better, but I don't have an immediate proof.

---

That said, although usually stated for $\mathsf{ZF+DC}$ Shoenfield absoluteness in fact holds for $\mathsf{ZF}$ models; see [this answer of Dorais](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23920/8133). The point is that we don't need *full* Mostowski absoluteness in the proof of Shoenfield.

Comment: Suppose that $M$ is a transitive model of height $\alpha\geq\omega_1$ for $\alpha\neq\beth_\alpha$. Force to collapse $\alpha$ to be countable. In $V[G]$ there is $N$ of size $\beth_\alpha^{V[G]}$, but since the collapsing forcing is of size $\alpha<\beth_\alpha$, we can cover this set with ground model sets. Can we use that to prove the model existed in $V$ somehow?

Comment: Is Andres's 4x upvoted comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/129715) wrong then (the not even choice part), or are there some assumptions beyond ZFC to that Friedman result? (I don't see an obvious reason why any model of ZF needs to be countable in $L_{\alpha_1}$ just cause $L_{\alpha_0}$ is countable there, but maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen At a glance I don't agree with Andres' comment there, but I could easily be missing something. I've asked for clarification.